# How to do a custom validator that tests if one of 2 datetime properties is larger than another in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this class called DateTimeViewModelNullable where I have a method that returns a DateTime?

```
public DateTime? GetDateTime
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime date;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(Date, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, ParseInt(Hour), ParseInt(Minute), 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I then have 2 properties of that type in a viewmodel
        public DateTimeViewModelNullable DateOut { get; set; }

```
    [CustomIsValidDate(DateOut.GetDateTime,DateIn.GetDateTime,ErrorMessage = "Returning date must be higher than ingoing date!")]
    public DateTimeViewModelNullable DateIn { get; set; }
```

I need to ensure (And print for the user) if the startdate is greater than the enddate so I created the customvalidator, but dont work

```
public class CustomIsValidDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }


    public CustomIsValidDate(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (StartDate == null || EndDate == null)
            return true;
        if (EndDate > StartDate)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

I get the error Error   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Answer (score 0):

You are using static variable in `GetDateTime` method, you have to remove that.

Comment: I quite dont follow. do you have an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just use two datetime? properties on your model and implement System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject on this model as below:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validations = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (From.HasValue && Until.HasValue)
        {
            if (From.Value.Date < Until.Value.Date)
                validations.Add(new ValidationResult("StartDateMustBeBeforeEndDate"));
            else if (From.Value.Date == From.Value.Date 
                        && From.Value.Hour < Until.Value.Hour)
                validations.Add(new ValidationResult("StartHourMustBeBeforeEndHour"));
            else if (From.Value.Date == From.Value.Date 
                        && From.Value.Hour == Until.Value.Hour 
                        && From.Value.Minute < Until.Value.Minute)
                validations.Add(new ValidationResult("StartMinuteMustBeBeforeEndMinute"));
        }

        return validations;
    }
```

Comment: So you want me not to use my DateTimeViewModelNullable? I cant see how I can validate the Date, Hour and Miniute textfields individually then?

Comment: I added some extra rules where you can check on the fact that the From Date must be bigger then the enddate and if the dates are the same that the from hour must be before the endour and the same for minutes. I hope this helps you.